# pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Temporary GCS path has not been set

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

On Google Cloud Platform, I am trying to submit a pyspark job that writes a dataframe to BigQuery.
The code that executes the writing is as the following:

```
finalDF.write.format("bigquery")\
.mode('overwrite')\
.option("table","[PROJECT_ID].dataset.table")\
.save()
```

And I get the mentioned error in the title. How can I set the GCS temporary path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the github [repository of spark-bigquery-connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector) states

One can specify it when writing:

```
df.write
.format("bigquery")
.option("temporaryGcsBucket","some-bucket")
.save("dataset.table")
```

Or in a global manner:

```
spark.conf.set("temporaryGcsBucket","some-bucket")
```

Answer (score 1):

Property "temporaryGcsBucket" needs to be set either at the time of writing dataframe or while creating sparkSession.

.option("temporaryGcsBucket","some-bucket")

or like .option("temporaryGcsBucket","some-bucket/optional_path")

`1. finalDF.write.format("bigquery") .mode('overwrite').option("temporaryGcsBucket","some-bucket").option("table","[PROJECT_ID].dataset.table") .save()`